# Como faço para atualizar várias linhas de uma tabela após a mesma sofrer uma determinada alteração?

Tags: sql, oracle, pl-sql

```
  CREATE or REPLACE TRIGGER TG_ATUALIZA_BLOQUEIO AFTER UPDATE ON pcclient
  FOR EACH ROW
  begin
  if :NEW.BLOQUEIO = 'S' THEN
  UPDATE PCCLIENT SET BLOQUEIO='S' where codcliprinc=:OLD.CODCLIPRINC;
  END IF;
  end TG_ATUALIZA_BLOQUEIO;
```

Explicando:

Após bloquear um cliente `BLOQUEIO='S'` os demais clientes da mesma rede serão bloqueados:

```
UPDATE PCCLIENT SET BLOQUEIO='S' where codcliprinc=:OLD.CODCLIPRINC;
```

Comment: Qual a dúvida exatamente? Não entendi

Comment: ESSES CLIENTES SÃO AMARRADOS PELO COCLIPRINC;

OBJETIVO:            

QUANDO O USUÁRIO BLOQUEAR UM CLIENTE A TRIGGER DEVERÁ BLOQUEAR TODOS OS CLIENTES COM O MESMO CODCLIPRINC.

Comment: Só que é exatamente dessa forma, através do `OLD.CODCLIPRINC` tu pega qual é o CodCliPrinc que foi alterado, única coisa "estranha" que vejo no seu exemplo é o "=:" remove os dois pontos

Comment: Meu BD é Oracle!

Comment: Vou tentar Maicon!

Comment: Não deu certo dá erro!

Comment: Qual erro está dando?

Comment: ORA-04091: a tabela HR.PCCLIENT é mutante; talvez o gatilho/função não possa localizá-la
ORA-06512: em "HR.TG_ATUALIZA_BLOQUEIO", line 5
ORA-04088: erro durante a execução do gatilho 'HR.TG_ATUALIZA_BLOQUEIO'
04091. 00000 -  "table %s.%s is mutating, trigger/function may not see it"
*Cause:    A trigger (or a user defined plsql function that is referenced in
           this statement) attempted to look at (or modify) a table that was
           in the middle of being modified by the statement which fired it.
*Action:   Rewrite the trigger (or function) so it does not read that table.

Comment: Pelo o que vi o `ORACLE` não permite criar uma trigger que altera a própria tabela (evitar loop infinito)

Comment: Então vou ter que criar uma Stored Procedure e chama-la na Trigger?

Comment: Não sei se tem alguma solução mais fácil, mas eu faria um DELETE e INSERT

Comment: Necessitas mesmo de um trigger? Porque não fazer o update de uma só vez?

Comment: A trigger pode ser de STATEMENT , creio ,  mas requer atenção pois ela é recursiva , não lembro se a opção ON DELETE CASCADE pode ser usada na mesma tabela mas ainda existe o problema da recursividade. No sistema existe algo que garante que A não seja principal de B e B seja ao mesmo tempo principal de A. Talvez seja melhor fazer uma procedure e chamar pela aplicação , um cursor com connect by deve resolver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom, está claro que está rolando um ***loop infinito***, veja só.

Existe uma *trigger* que, no `UPDATE` do campo `BLOQUEIO` para `S`, ele faz `UPDATE` no campo `BLOQUEIO` também para `S`.

Eu não gosto de TRIGGER. É um recurso que não fica claro no fluxo de execução da aplicação. Então minha primeira recomendação é que faça uma verificação, no lado da aplicação, onde, se bloquear um usuário, em seguida, bloqueia todos os demais da mesma rede.

Mas, dando uma segunda sugestão para a Trigger, tente o seguinte:

```
CREATE or REPLACE TRIGGER TG_ATUALIZA_BLOQUEIO AFTER UPDATE ON pcclient
FOR EACH ROW
declare
   v_id NUMBER;
   v_exists NUMBER;
begin

if :NEW.BLOQUEIO = 'S' THEN

-- VERIFICA SE EXISTE OUTROS USUARIOS DA MESMA REDE AINDA NÃO BLOQUEADOS
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO v_exists FROM DUAL 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM PCCLIENT WHERE CODCLIPRINC = :OLD.CODCLIPRINC AND BLOQUEIO <> 'S' AND ID <> :OLD.ID);

-- SE EXISTIR
IF V_EXISTS > 0 THEN
   -- PEGA O ID DE UM DESSES USUARIOS
   SELECT ID into V_ID FROM PCCLIENT WHERE CODCLIPRINC = :OLD.CODCLIPRINC AND ID <> :OLD.ID AND ROWNUM = 1;

   -- BLOQUEIA O CARA
   -- IMPORTANTE!!! AQUI IRA DISPARAR O TRIGGER NOVAMENTE, 
   -- BLOQUEANDO OS USUARIO EM CASCATA
   UPDATE PCCLIENT SET BLOQUEIO='S' where ID = V_ID;

END IF


END IF;
end TG_ATUALIZA_BLOQUEIO;
```

Answer (score 1):

Você terá que acionar a trigger sempre que houver a alteração na tabela.

Abaixo segue exemplo em SQL:

```
--criei a tabela cliente
CREATE TABLE CLIENTE (
ID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
NOME VARCHAR (250),
BLOQUEADO VARCHAR (1),
REDE VARCHAR (20)
)
```

Abaixo faço o insert na tabela cliente com REDE 1 e REDE 2

```
INSERT INTO CLIENTE (NOME,BLOQUEADO,REDE) VALUES
('CLIENTE1REDE1', 'N', 'REDE1'),
('CLIENTE2REDE1', 'N', 'REDE1'),
('CLIENTE3REDE1', 'N', 'REDE1'),
('CLIENTE4REDE1', 'N', 'REDE1'),
('CLIENTE5REDE1', 'N', 'REDE1'),
('CLIENTE6REDE1', 'N', 'REDE1'),
('CLIENTE7REDE1', 'N', 'REDE1'),
('CLIENTE8REDE1', 'N', 'REDE1'),
('CLIENTE9REDE2', 'N', 'REDE2'),
('CLIENTE1REDE2', 'N', 'REDE2'),
('CLIENTE2REDE2', 'N', 'REDE2'),
('CLIENTE3REDE2', 'N', 'REDE2'),
('CLIENTE4REDE2', 'N', 'REDE2'),
('CLIENTE5REDE2', 'N', 'REDE2'),
('CLIENTE6REDE2', 'N', 'REDE2'),
('CLIENTE7REDE2', 'N', 'REDE2'),
('CLIENTE8REDE2', 'N', 'REDE2'),
('CLIENTE9REDE2', 'N', 'REDE2');
```

Depois crio a trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[ATUALIZA_BLOQUEIO]
ON [dbo].[CLIENTE]
FOR UPDATE
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE
    @ID INT,
    @BLOQUEADO VARCHAR (1),
    @REDE VARCHAR(20)

    SELECT @ID = ID, @REDE = REDE, @BLOQUEADO = BLOQUEADO FROM inserted

--Verifico se o valor do cliente que foi alterado esta 
--como bloqueado, caso esteja repasso para os demais
--clientes da mesma rede
    IF (@BLOQUEADO = 'S')
    BEGIN
    UPDATE CLIENTE SET BLOQUEADO = 'S' WHERE REDE = @REDE
    END
    END
```

Faço um update em um cliente especifico para teste

```
UPDATE CLIENTE SET BLOQUEADO = 'S' WHERE NOME = 'CLIENTE8REDE2'
```

Faço o select para verificar (veja que alterou todos os clientes da rede 2)

```
SELECT * FROM CLIENTE
```

Espero ajudar

Observação: Em oracle pode mudar um pouco a dinâmica na criação da trigger, mas somente um pouco da sintaxe.

Comment: Mas o banco de dados dele é Oracle.